# Dynamically Set GitHub Actions Secrets on Docker Container Build/Run Command with bash/shell

Tags: docker, bash, shell, github-actions

I'm in the early stages of building an automated pipeline. Still in the exploring phase. Right now, I'm struggling with setting the environment variables for the container I'm going to run my app and exploring a few different approaches.

The idea is to have my environment variables set as GitHub Actions Secrets and configure them in the container when I run the docker container command. The container was built out of a Docker Composer file.

One of the approaches I had in mind would be like this:

```
  - name: Backend - Build Container (proof of concept)
    run: |
      declare -a SECRET_KEYS=("GITHUB_USER" "GITHUB_REPO_NAME" "TEST_1" "TEST_2");
      for key in "${SECRET_KEYS[@]}"; do
        ENV_VARS+="$key=\"\${{ secrets.$key }}\" "
      done
      BACKEND_CONTAINER_SH_SCRIPT="$ENV_VARS docker-compose -f ss-build-files/ubuntu-container-build.yml up -d && docker-compose -f ss-build-files/ubuntu-container-build.yml logs; exit;";
      ssh -v -t -t -i id_rsa_ssh_key_server_temp.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_IP }} "$BACKEND_CONTAINER_SH_SCRIPT"
```

Essentially, would loop through an array, which I would build dynamically in another section of the code. Then, set all of them in a loop.

Would this be possible to accomplish? If so, what would I be missing here in the syntax, as it's erroring.